# AsyncGPUReadback.RequestIntoNativeArray - owner has been invalidated

Tags: unity, c#, gpu, async, array

I have the following C# code in Unity version  2022.2.0a12:

```
[SerializeField]
public bool isLoging = true;

[SerializeField]
private RenderTexture _rt;
private NativeArray<byte> _data;

private void Start()
{
    CreateBuffer(ref _data, ref _rt);
    StartCoroutine(StartEncoding(_rt, isLoging));
}


System.Collections.IEnumerator StartEncoding(RenderTexture oRTs, bool active)
{
    while (active)
    {

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        AsyncGPUReadback.RequestIntoNativeArray(ref _data, oRTs, 0, request =>
        {
            if (request.hasError) { 
                Debug.Log("GPU readback error detected."); 
                return;
            }
            Debug.Log("in Function ");
            // encode to png and save 
            Debug.Log("saved PNG file ");
        });


    }
}

void CreateBuffer(ref NativeArray<byte> buffer, ref RenderTexture oRTS)
{
    buffer = new NativeArray<byte>(oRTS.height * oRTS.width * 4, Allocator.Persistent, NativeArrayOptions.UninitializedMemory);
}

private void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    _data.Dispose();
}
```

Before even the first frame ends I get this error:

> `1[System.Byte]` can no longer be accessed, since its owner has been invalidated.

What is happening? I can get date to be used once and then I cannot use it anymore?

My question is how can I use `AsyncGPUReadback.RequestIntoNativeArray` correctly so I do not lose access to my `NativeArray`?

I would like to hold on my data and pass it to Job so inside job i can do encoding to PNG .

Comment: What Unity version are you using? [There was a bug where Unity would incorrectly dispose of a `NativeArray`](https://forum.unity.com/threads/asyncgpureadback-requestintonativearray-causes-invalidoperationexception-on-nativearray.1011955/), but [the issue tracker reports this as fixed in 2020.3.X, 2021.2.X, and 2022.1.X](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/asyncgpureadback-dot-requestintonativearray-causes-invalidoperationexception-on-nativearray). If you're on an older version, you may need to upgrade, or use the workaround in the first thread I linked.

Comment: it was 2020.3.26f now i am opening in 2022.2.0a12 but this version just crash so i will need to make new project in new version .

Comment: @DMGregory same result in  2022.2.0a12 version .